# Python: Calculating total distance path

Tags: python, loops, distance, python-turtle

I have a program which is meant to calculate the total distance of a set of coordinates for a Python Turtle. At the moment, I have a function called def calculate_distance which calculates the distance between two points only. I need to:

- set up a variable to hold the total path distance
- use a loop to calculate the distance of the points individually
- try and use the calculate_distance function
- calculate the path of all locations returning to the original

How would I go about doing this? I am new to Python but I know majority of the basics. This is what my program displays at the end:

distance between points: 72.59476565152615 - but this is between two points and not the total

```
import math

selected_map = [(12, 34), (45, -55), (-89, 33), (60, 12)]

def calculate_distance(starting_x, starting_y, destination_x, destination_y):
    distance = math.hypot(destination_x - starting_x, destination_y - starting_y)  # calculates Euclidean distance (straight-line) distance between two points
    return distance

def calculate_path(selected_map):

- The code I am asking for help on needs to go here in this function



print (distance)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
selected_map = [(12, 34), (45, -55), (-89, 33), (60, 12)]

def calculate_distance(starting_x, starting_y, destination_x, destination_y):
    distance = math.hypot(destination_x - starting_x, destination_y - starting_y)  # calculates Euclidean distance (straight-line) distance between two points
    print('Segment Dist: ', distance)
    return distance

def calculate_path(selected_map, dist_travel=0):
    for i in range(len(selected_map)-1):
        dist_travel += calculate_distance(selected_map[i-len(selected_map)+1][0], selected_map[i-len(selected_map)+1][1], selected_map[i][0], selected_map[i][1])
    return dist_travel

print('Total Distance: ', calculate_path(selected_map))
```

Output:

```
Segment Dist:  94.92101980067429
Segment Dist:  160.31219541881399
Segment Dist:  150.4725888658795
Total Distance:  405.70580408536773
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the length of a path (e.g. total distance as you mentioned, not net displacement), just iterate through each point and compute its distance from the last point traversed:

```
import math

def calculate_distance(starting_x, starting_y, destination_x, destination_y):
    distance = math.hypot(destination_x - starting_x, destination_y - starting_y)  # calculates Euclidean distance (straight-line) distance between two points
    return distance

def calculate_path(selected_map):
    total_distance = 0
    current_point = selected_map[0]
    for next_point in selected_map[1:]:
        current_distance = calculate_distance(
            current_point[0], current_point[1],
            next_point[0], next_point[1]
        )
        print(current_point, 'to', next_point, '=', current_distance)
        total_distance += current_distance
        current_point = next_point
    return total_distance

selected_map = [(12, 34), (45, -55), (-89, 33), (60, 12)]
distance = calculate_path(selected_map)

print ('Total Distance =', distance)
```

Output:

```
(12, 34) to (45, -55) = 94.92101980067429
(45, -55) to (-89, 33) = 160.31219541881399
(-89, 33) to (60, 12) = 150.4725888658795
Total Distance = 405.70580408536773
```

Comment: How would this code work if I had to make a loop that randomly generated the coordinates instead of me giving ones of my own choice?

Comment: @user2009 just create a list and assign it to `selected_map` and add random coordinates to it, or change the `selected_map = [(12, 34), (45, -55), (-89, 33), (60, 12)]` line with `selected_map = generate_map()` and define a function `generate_map()` that returns a list of random coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to define the starting point. For example, defining two variables of the current location.

```
x_current = 0
y_current = 0
```

And a varible which save the current length.

```
current_length = 0
```

Then you start looping over the selected_map. calculating the distance betweent the current x,y and the pair x,y and adding it into current length.

```
for pair in selected_map:
  current_length += calculate_distance(x_current, y_current, pair[0], pair[1])
  x_current = pair[0]
  x_current = pair[1]

return current_length
```